# It is found that diamgnetic materials weigh less when placed in a magnetic field.Why?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I've always had this question as to why diamagnetic materials weigh less when places in a magnetic field but I haven't found the answer on books or online so far .

Comment: Can you send a reference that says a diamagnetic material weighs less in a magnetic field?

Comment: Check gouy's experiment.I believe it's proved through that.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there's a misunderstanding.  A diamagnetic material experiences a force directed "uphill" in a magnetic field: in the direction in which the field density decreases.  A ferromagnetic material experiences a force in the "downhill" direction: in which the field density increases.  But "uphill" and "downhill" in this sense have nothing to do with the "up" and "down" of gravity.  If you place a diamagnetic object on a scale and hold a magnet above it, the object will seem to weigh more (because the magnetic field is stronger near the magnet).  With a ferromagnetic object, the opposite will happen.

**Edit 12/21/18:** The [Gouy Balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouy_balance) does precisely as is explained above, except that the magnet is below the object instead of above it.  *Gravity is not altered* by the magnetic field or by the properties of the object.  There is simply an added magnetic force which, depending on the arrangement of the apparatus, is either upward or downward.  Note that if the string supporting the object is a bit longer so that the object is below the poles of the magnet, the added force will be in the downward direction.

Comment: It's proved through gouy's experiment.